# Return a Column Type cursor on cursor in jpa hibernate5 spring4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a big problem with my webservice that i have a procedure which return a cursor. But in that cursor i also have a column with type is cursor so how i can define this column for my entities class. I'm using `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` anotation. when i try to run that proc in my webservice it's return ->

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

thank for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This stored procedure returns a cursor output parameter, and has one input parameter.
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "ReadAddressById",
    resultClasses = Address.class,
    procedureName = "READ_ADDRESS",
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=IN, name="P_ADDRESS_ID", type=Long.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=REF_CURSOR, name="CUR_ADDRESS", type=void.class)
    }
)
@Entity
public class Address {
  ...
}

//Example calling a named stored procedure with a cursor output parameter
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("ReadAddressById");
query.setParameter("P_ADDRESS_ID", 12345);
query.execute();
List<Address> result = (List<Address>)query.getOutputParameterValue("CUR_ADDRESS");
```

Comment: thank for you help.But i Have a cursor and in this cursor i have a column type a cursor too. Not a single cursor like your example.

Comment: Instead of  column type a cursor.if it is possible to use oracle types.